# inconsitent rendering on refresh in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, backbone.js, dust.js

On initial load, all the views and models load perfectly in IE8. On refresh it makes all the necessary calls but not rendering some of the templates. Once the cache is cleared, everything works fine on refresh.

Can anyone advise on IE8 refresh issue.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using some ajax calls be aware that IE can cache them too causing some strange behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your ajax calls are not being cached

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Comment: yes all ajax calls have cache false setting. its just 1 view not rendering on refresh, other views render good.